# How to pass php variable into a class function?

Tags: php, function, variables

I want to pass php variable `$aa` into a class function. I have read [some articles](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) 
in php.net, but I still don't understand well. Can anyone help me put the variable into this class? thanks.

```
$aa='some word';
class Action {
    private $_objXML;
    private $_arrMessages = array();
    public function __construct() {        
        $this->_objXML = simplexml_load_file($aa.'.xml');
    }
}
```

Comment: The linked article is about passing by reference, is that what you want/need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean... do you mean you want to access $aa in a function? If so:

```
$aa='some word';
class Action {
    private $_objXML;
    private $_arrMessages = array();
    public function __construct() {
        global $aa;
        $this->_objXML = simplexml_load_file($aa.'.xml');
    }
}
```

Or, on a per instance basis, you can do things like:

```
$aa='some word';
class Action {
    private $_objXML;
    private $_arrMessages = array();
    public function __construct($aa) {
        $this->_objXML = simplexml_load_file($aa.'.xml');
    }
}
new Action($aa);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply put the variable names in the constructor.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```
public function __construct( $aa )
{
   // some content here
}
```

Comment: Note, though, that the variable in the function has *no connection* to the variable outside of it.  It's common, but not necessary, to name it the same.  But changing `$aa` in the function won't change the value of the real `$aa`, unless `$aa` is an object (as of PHP 5) or you pass it by reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
$aa='some word';
class Action {
    private $_objXML;
    private $_arrMessages = array();
    public function __construct($aa) {        
        $this->_objXML = simplexml_load_file($aa.'.xml');
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$instance = new Action('something');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php, but my logic and google say this:

```
class Action {
    private $_objXML;
    private $_arrMessages = array();
    public function __construct($aa) {        
        $this->_objXML = simplexml_load_file($aa.'.xml');
   }
}

$object = new Action('some word');
```

This is simply called pass a variable as parameter of a function, in this case the function is the constructor of Action